# Filling array using array from function

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to fill a 2d array in function `drawInitialNim()`, using values passed from main.

```
int drawInitialBoard(int x, int y, int z);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int board[3][50] = {{0}};
    int row1, row2, row3;
    int i, j;

    row1 = 0;
    row2 = 0;
    row3 = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of rocks in each row: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &row1, &row2, &row3); //values for amount of "O" in the array
    printf("this is row 1: %d\n", row1); //debug
    board[2][49] = drawInitialBoard(row1, row2, row3); //fill array from function

    printf("this is 0,0 in main: %d\n",board[0][0]); // debug

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) { //print indexes that contain "O" or 79
        printf("Row %d: ", i+1);
        for (j=0; j<50; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] != 0) {
                printf("%c", board[i][j]);
            }
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

int drawInitialBoard(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int i,j,k;
    static int arr[3][50] = {{0}};

    for (i=0; i<x; i++) { //fill board with "O", or its that equal 79
        arr[0][i] = 'O';
    }
    for (j=0; j<y; j++) {
        arr[1][j] = 'O';
    }
    for (k=0; k<z; k++) {
        arr[2][k] = 'O';
    }
    printf("This is 0,0 in the function: %d\n", arr[0][0]); //debug
    return **arr;
}
```

I am getting this output, using `1, 2, 3` as input for `x, y, z` in main:
Row 1: 
Row 2: 
Row 3: O

I feel like the values from `drawInitialNim()` are not getting passed to main properly. I know that arrays can't be returned, so I returned the pointer. Additionally, I don't think that this is a dereferencing problem. I am not sure how to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "so I returned the pointer". Actually you returned the first value (ie. `arr[0][0]`).

Comment: The return type of your `drawInitialBoard` is `int` and you are trying to return a double pointer from the function. Doesn't seem good.

Comment: and what output are you getting???

Answer (score 0):

See the first thing I see incorrect in your program is:
You define the function like `int drawInitialBoard(int x, int y, int z);` which means that it will give back an `int` but you are returning `**arr`. Now according to what I know, `*` means "value at address of" so `*arr` would mean value at address of the pointer arr. And as `arr` is an array it is a pointer to its first element. So I think there is something wrong in there when you use `return **arr`. And as the first element in the array is not a pointer then I think that `**arr` would probably just give you not what you desire.

Comment: further even if you resolve this problem, then you are receiving it in `board[2][49]` which is not a pointer and is an array block of type `int`

Comment: So, should I declare the function as `int **drawInitialNim(...)`?

Comment: @user1753491 I am not sure what do you want to achieve with that exactly but this wont work. See in declaration * means a pointer and ** means a double pointer. So if you do int**draw.... then it would be expected to return a double pointer. But when you return something like *arr then it means value at the address of pointer arr. And it returns the value Not the pointer. So i guess your best bet would be to review  your code again and read  a bit about pointers and arrays and how to pass them between functions

Comment: @user1753491 And if you take my suggestion, try an online compiler like ideone.com and put the program in there, debug it, remove the scanf lines and put sample values directly in the program and work on that. And you can share the link here for people to see what the output is exactly. And it would make easier for people here to help.

Comment: The output is near the end of my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declaring an array, filling the rows according to the arguments passed, and then returning the value of `arr[0][0]`, which in the case of the input values you state is 79 or 'O'. This value is then written to the main array `board[2][49]` and you then report correctly on its contents - all other elements are still 0. I don't see why you are using two arrays, not just one. And I don't see why you have declared an `int` array when you are treating it as a `char` array.

Comment: I am using an int array because I don't want to use a char array. I need to print Os, and I can do that with int, even though the "real" value is 79.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to make you program work would be, make your array `board[3][50]` global.
And, change the return type of your function `drawInitialBoard(int x, int y, int z);` to `void`, i.e., `void drawInitialBoard(int x, int y, int z);`.
And instead of working on a new array `arr` in the function, you can use the array defined previously `board[3][50]`.

This won't clear the concept of passing the 2-D array, but will surely make it work.